# Android dp to px rounding

Tags: android, layout

[image: Blue view height: 32dp]

[image: Blue and white views height: 4dp]

In the first picture the blue view height is 32dp
In the second picture blue and white views height are both 4dp

In both pictures the rose view has marginTop 32dp

The rose view in the second picture should not overlap because 4dp times 8 should be 32dp, but it isn't.

Probably android always rounds to exact pixels, and the overlapping is because of the rounding. Or does anyone has an other explanation for that?

Comment: What model device is that?

Comment: Emulator: Nexus 5X API 27 x86

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using a margin to try to align like that.  Use a RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout.  But yes, Android rounds.  A realistic dpi is something like 332.  A dp is 1/160th of an inch.  Since pixels only work in whole numbers, there isn't an exact mapping.  If you add 4dp of padding 8 times, you'd round down each time.  But adding 32 dp in one shot may round up, depending on exact density.